# Filling tkinter listbox from a different class

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

In my gui I want to import data from a file, display it in a listbox, do a computation, show the result in a listbox and then export the data as a csv.
I have been able to do most of the GUI but the interaction between classes makes no sense to me, here is my code:

```
class MainApplication(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        self.master = master
        self.container = tk.Frame(self)
        self.container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        self.frames["computation"] = computation(master=self.container, controller=self)
        self.frames["openFile"] = openFile(master=self.container, controller=self)
    ...
    def get_page(self, c):
        return self.frames[c]

class computation(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.controller = controller
        self.listbox = Listbox(self.master)
        self.listbox.pack()

    def add_listbox_item(self):
        for i in df.columns:
            self.listbox.insert(END,i)

class openFile(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.controller = controller
        self.openfile = Button(self.master, command=self.import_df)

   def import_df(self):
       self.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(...)
       global df
       df = pd.read_csv(self.filename)
       computation = self.controller.get_page("computation")
       computation.add_listbox_item()
```

Everything seems to be executing, even a print statement in add_listbox_item but the listbox just wont be filled with the data it's being fed, any ideas?

Comment: Please fix the indentation errors in your code. `__init__` is not properly indented inside `MainApplication`. Also, what have you done to debug this? Have you verified that `df.columns` returns what you think it is returning?

Comment: `computation.add_list_item()` should be `computation.add_listbox_item()` instead.  Also better pass `df` to `add_listbox_item()` instead of using global variable.